# 'Certificate must have an ExtendedKeyUsage extension.' and 'Error Loading extension section config.cnf'

Tags: java, ubuntu, openssl, cryptography, bouncycastle

Using Bouncy Castle to generate timestamps. I originally created the certificate using

`sudo openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout private.key -out cert.crt` but got the error `Certificate must have an ExtendedKeyUsage extension.`.

So following the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13332694/create-tsa-timestamping-certificate-with-openssl-add-a-extendedkeyusage-in-a) and adding a config file, I got the error `unable to find 'distinguished_name' in config - problems making Certificate Request`

I tried the instructions [here](https://superuser.com/questions/947061/openssl-unable-to-find-distinguished-name-in-config), but then got the error `Error Loading extension section req`.

The simplest config I've used is this, but I've also tried others which including the organization such as a modified version of [this one](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/apps/openssl.cnf), but no luck.

```
[req]
distinguished_name = req_distinguished_name
```

The commands I've tried:

```
sudo openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout private.key -out cert.crt -config config.cnf

sudo openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout private.key -out cert.crt -extensions req

sudo openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout private.key -out cert.crt -config config.cnf -extensions req
```

some posts reference an `-ext-file` switch, but this is not available.

Comment: does this answer help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43929436/subject-alternative-name-missing-err-ssl-version-or-cipher-mismatch/44058453#44058453

Comment: Agree with Oleg. A distinguished name is specified in X500 and should consist of multiple components. If a string is directly accepted then it should be in the form "CN = <name> (etc)" rather than just "req_distinguished_name".

Comment: Thanks to you both for taking a minute to read my question. I've looked at the linked suggestion but I'm still missing something. I'm using the simplest certificate possible and the suggestion has a lot of pieces I don't understand. Would prefer to get this working with as few variables as possible. Other than the sample config you supply, to be honest, I would not have thought these questions even related. 1. Why do the ones I link to not have additional stuff, 2. are the fields in [] (ex. [req]) predefined or am I making them whatever I want and referencing them with the extensions switch?